# Which video editing software would fit this specific goal for YouTube?

Tags: video-editing, youtube, animation

I am looking to start a YouTube channel and am happy to take the time to learn the appropriate tools, but I am confused as to which video editor would make the most sense to invest time in, since I don't have the experience to know in advance where the returns are.

These would be my requirements:

- Good automation process tools and plugins that help streamline the video workflow once your learn how to use them. 90% of the video length would involve a voice track over stock photos and stock (or at least pre-existing) footage.
- Ideally avoiding a monthly subscription payment model as opposed to a lump sum or no cost
- Good interoperability and plugins with Audacity (or any other recording software that I can learn) or basically anything that can optimize the workflow with the audio voice-over track such as cleaning up breaks and mouth noise.
- Support for creating relatively simple and short animations involving hand-drawn characters

Basically, the idea is that I want to find software that will provide sufficient capacity and customization to reward long-term investment. The ideal situation would be if it offered all this while also having a beginner-friendly interface and QoL features, but that is perhaps a self-contradictory demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look no further than DaVinci Resolve.

As an edit suite it's right up there with the best. It has pretty much every audio tool [look at the 'Fairlight' section in the link] you could wish for & if you want more, it takes VST plugins.
It's not simple. You can't really walk up to it & make a hit video in ten minutes. There's a learning curve. There's a 1,000-page manual too. It is, though, hugely powerful. You won't need to learn another suite.

…and what's more - it's multi-platform, Win, Mac, Nix - and **absolutely free**, as in beer.
There's a paid version if you need to integrate edit suite hardware.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it is the best solution.